# No wallpaper in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, desktop-background

Hi there wonderful people ! I just updated my Ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10 , and my desktop has turned black ! No wallpaper for me.In the "Appearance" I am able to see all the wallpapers ,  but am not able to set them on the desktop ! Please help ...

Thanks..

Comment: Can you see icons on the desktop (if you have some of them on it of course)?

Answer (score 0):

ok its quite a while ago... but until today i was searching for the answer, had SAME problem... gnome made it. here you find it->

https://www.rubysecurity.org/ubuntu_unity-black-background

have a nice wallpaper-day, 
mat

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.